# Big O notation compare inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, asymptotics

This seems very basic but can not figure it out.
I have

$a = C_{1} \delta
\\
|b| = \sqrt{B} \delta, \ B \neq 0$

where $\delta >0$

so both can be written as

$a = O(\delta)
\\b = O(\delta)$

and $\delta \to 0$

Why can't I say

$\exists \ C\geq (>?) 0: \quad |a| \leq C |b|$.

I could write
$\delta = \frac{|b|}{\sqrt{B}}$

and
$|a| = | C_{1} \delta| \leq | C_{1} | \delta = |b| \frac{| C_{1} |}{\sqrt{B}}$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: If $C_1$  and $B$ are constants then you are not wrong. But if you only know that $a=O(\delta)=b$ as $\delta\to 0$ then you don't know that $C$ exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me bring example for sequences. Consider
$$g(n)= \begin{cases}{}
\frac{1}{n}, & n=2k\\ 
0, & n=2k-1
\end{cases}$$
and
$$f(n)= \begin{cases}{}
0, & n=2k\\ 
\frac{1}{n}, & n=2k-1
\end{cases}$$
then both holds $f,g \in O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, but you cannot write $f \leqslant C g$ or $g \leqslant C f$.